# Ajax update javascript script in primefaces

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to ajax update javascript script using with primefaces.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function lineChartExtender(){
        this.cfg.highlighter = {
            showTooltip: true,
            tooltipAxes: 'both',
            tooltipLocation: 'n'
        };
        this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                showMarker: #{query.stringMarker}
        };
    }        -->
    </script>
```

How I can do that value in showMarker will be ajax update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in a JSF tag, and give it Id.

```
<h:panelGroup id="myScript">
   <script type="text/javascript">

     function lineChartExtender(){
         this.cfg.highlighter = {
             showTooltip: true,
             tooltipAxes: 'both',
             tooltipLocation: 'n'
        };
         this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
                 showMarker: #{query.stringMarker}
         };
      }       
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and have a button or link that does some action, or not, and updates this `<h:panelGroup>`

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.doSomething}" update="myScript"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for help. Also problem was that I added comment in script section(<!-- -->) when I delete it from script and component to rendered all is correct.

Comment: in script use JavaScript comments `//`

Comment: I had a comment in my script section too (copied from PrimeFaces documentation) - and this produced a "parser error" in PrimeFaces partial update